# Brown/Unclickable part of Google Maps

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, google-maps

I'm new in using Google maps and I encountered this problem where when i change the size of the container of the maps,there is a brown part in my Maps that is Unclickable and undraggable

I made a button that closes a div and changes the size of the container of my Google Maps

Here is the Jquery that Changes the size of the Divs and map container

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHandler() {
        $('#hides').toggle();
        $('#shows').toggle()
        $('#settings').toggleClass('col-sm-9 col-sm-12');
        $('#resultcontainer').toggle('slow');

    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#shows').hide();
        $('#hides, #shows').on('click', clickHandler);

</script>
```

Here is the Screenshots:

As you can see, there's a brown part on the right side of the second photo that is unclickable and undraggable

[image]

[image]

This is my Initialize with Bounds set for USA

```
function initialize() {
            var minZoomLevel = 4;
            var zooms = 7;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50);
            var addresse = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: LatLang,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), addresse);

            // Bounds for North America
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                      new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
                      new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90));

            // Listen for the dragend event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
                // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                var c = map.getCenter(),
                      x = c.lng(),
                      y = c.lat(),
                      maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                      maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                      minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                      minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                if (x < minX) x = minX;
                if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                if (y < minY) y = minY;
                if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });

            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading google map when the container size is changed?

Comment: @Froient yah, tried that and same thing happens

Comment: @Froient wait sir, ill post my Initialize codes

Comment: If you are changing the size of map container then according to google docs: *Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`.*

Comment: @AntoJurković sir thank you , but can i know where can i enter that event in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` function (so it wont affect your current activity with the map) on the event handler just after you resized your container.

For Example, this is where you change the size of your map container:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#map").toggleClass("larger");
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

While, in the case of the brown lines in your map, I think there is/are element/s that is affecting it. You might want to try z-indexing and put the map on the uppermost.

**Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/87p4F/3/)**

Comment: i think you nailed it sir Froient.. Thanks... 
Sir just a follow up question , as you can see , my maps have some sort of brown line across with it, any idea?

Comment: sir i think it did not work because when i filter some markers in map, and press the button, it loads again and removes all filtered marker